# Is it better to remove higher order interactions or least significant terms first in model simplification?

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, model-selection

I have a mixed effects model with 3 explanatory factors and a full interaction set (including 3 way interaction).  This is the full model.  Factor 1 is time and I am interested in the change in the response variable over time.  Therefore, only factors or interactions where time is present are biologically relevant.

My questions are:
1) Is it better to begin model simplification by removing the highest order (3-way) interaction first, or by removing the least significant term first (which in this case is factor 2)?  The 3 way interaction does actually have a relevant interpretation.  I have seen both options proposed.

2)Is it okay to include interactions but remove their basic factors (IE include time x treatment when treatment alone is removed from the model)? Several of the basic factors make no sense when not interacting with time.  IE measuring the effect of treatment when you are excluding time doesn't make much sense since starting conditions inside each treatment level are identical.

If my hypothesis is correct the final model should include several factor interactions but should not include basic factor 2 or 3 (as they make no sense in the absence of the time factor).

Thank you for your help.  I am happy to clarify if my question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Except in very unusual cases, you should not remove an effect and leave-in any effects that contain it. So if you find that the $AB$ interaction is significant, then don't throw out the main effects of $A$ or $B$. Similarly, don't keep $ABC$ and throw out $AB$, or $B$, or any other main effect or two-way interaction involving those three factors.

So, I recommend reading the ANOVA table from the bottom up. You can throw out stuff at the bottom to simplify the model, and work upward, keeping this effect hierarchy in mind.

To see, why, consider a simple illustration, where $A$ and $B$ both have two levels. Let $\mu_{ij}$ denote the expected response at the $i$th level of $A$ and the $j$th level of $B$. If you think that $A$ and $B$ interact, you are saying that the $A$ effects depend on $B$ and vice versa; and this is essentially the same as saying the the *combinations* of $A$ and $B$ should be regarded as levels of one factor (having 4 levels in this example). As such, the effects of this 4-level factor are quantified as contrasts $c_{11}\mu_{11}+c_{12}\mu_{12} + c_{21}\mu_{21} + c_{22}\mu_{22}$, where the $c_{ij}$ sum to zero. But if you exclude $A$ from the model, you are saying that the $A$ effect, $\{(\mu_{11}+\mu_{12}) - (\mu_{21}+\mu_{22})\}/2$ is equal to zero---thus limiting the contrasts you are willing to consider. Put another way, the four-level factor determined by the levels of $A$ and $B$ together has 3 degrees of freedom, but the interaction effect $AB$ has only 1 d.f.; the other two d.f. are covered by the $A$ and the $B$ main effects.

Comment: I fully agree, but was hoping to see some account of the reasons for these rules in your answer.  Although your (real-world) reputation lends weight to anything you might recommend, it is always better to appeal to objective reasons in support of any answer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  Out of curiosity, in what situations would it be acceptable to remove main effects but retain interactions?

Comment: I expanded my answer in response to @whuber.

Comment: To @MANOVAboard, I put it that way because I naturally hedge on making absolute statements. I can't think of a good example right now, but I can imagine *somebody* has one. It'd be a case where there is an inherent meaning to some interaction effect independent of one or more of the main effects containing it. Perhaps some kind of synergistic scenario or something.

Comment: It's interesting that you mention that, as that's what I am interpreting this situation as.  The data have repeated measures which are signified by the time factor.  Because I am interested in the effects of Factors 2 and 3 on the change in response variable (IE the interaction of factors 2 and 3 with time), the main effects of factors 2 and 3 don't make biological sense on their own.  The interpretation derived from the significance (or non) of the interactions should be unrelated to the significance of the main effects.  This thinking is biologically as opposed to statistically driven...

Comment: Also, thank you rvl for your clarification in the main answer, which I am wrapping my head around.  I suppose it would be acceptable to retain non-significant main effects if the interactions are significant, even if the main effects are biologically 'silly' on their own.

Comment: @MANOVAboard, In natural sciences and engineering we have good models, where we know the functional form of the process, e.g. the drag force is $\sim Area*Speed^2$. In this case, there's no need in main effects. This is rare in social sciences, where there are no good models.

Comment: Well, I can see both sides. If you have a viable scientific theory, then that trumps any statistical convention. However, if your theory is even slightly approximate, you can get into a mess by following it literally. What comes to mind are instances where people fit regression lines through the origin, based on the theory that the trend should be zero at zero. However, if all the data are all way out in right field, that origin constraint has a huge amount of leverage -- and the fitted trend, viewed local to the data actually at hand, can be totally ridiculous.

Comment: Continuing w/ regression thru the origin... So it is often better to include the intercept so that the model fits the data suitably, and understand that the model is locally approximate but there is some curvature between the origin and where the data are. On the other hand, if the data are already near the origin and your theory says the trend should pass through the origin, it' be fine to omit the intercept. It all hinges on being reasonable: all models are wrong, some are useful (quoting Box); avoid extrapolation, avoid being hog-tied by a distant constraint.

Comment: Now responding to @Aksakal, if all your areas and speeds are large, I'd still fit a model with the intercept and the main effects, as well as diagnostics for the simplified model you suggest.

Comment: @rvl, why would you fit a mis-specified model? You know all this stuff about biases etc.

Comment: Because the real world is dirtier than we think it is.

Comment: Thank you both for the enlightening conversation.  I have re-run the model taking out highest order (non-significant) interactions first and have settled on a model with a Time:Factor3 interaction.  Interestingly Factor 2 dropped out of all interactions and eventually the main effect itself was removed.  I arrived at a very different model this way but have more confidence in it.